# Change domain registrar from GoDaddy to Google

Tags: godaddy, google-workspace, domain-registrar

I would like to change domain registrar from GoDaddy to Google (with Google Apps services). But when I go on https://www.google.com/a/my_domain.com, I have this message:

> Sorry, you've reached a login page for a domain that isn't using Google Apps. Please check the web address and try again.

How can I do? Many thanks for your help.

Comment: Google is not a registrar.

Comment: @slaks are you sure ? I think you can ask google to register domains for you

Comment: @TobyAllen: Yes, but they just send you to an existing registrar.

Comment: GoDaddy is Google's default registrar: http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=59184

Answer (score 7, accepted):

SLaks is correct, Google is not a registrar, but [namecheap.com](http://www.namecheap.com), [hover.com](http://www.hover.com) and [networksolutions.com](http://www.networksolutions.com) are all registrars you could look into transferring for domain to. Here is a blog post on how to transfer from godaddy to namecheap.com: [blog.jeffepstein.me](http://blog.jeffepstein.me/post/14629857835/a-step-by-step-guide-to-transfer-domains-out-of-godaddy)

To setup a Google Apps go to https://www.google.com/a to setup your account. There is a little step by step setup that will help you get https://www.google.com/a/my_domain.com working.

I believe you will have to verify that you own the domain you are trying to setup. I just ended up putting a file publicly on my server to verify that I owned it.

Answer (score 2):

Go to https://www.google.com/a and click `Begin Free Trial` to set up Google Apps for your domain.

You will then need to set various DNS records with your registrar to redirect mail and domain names to Google servers.

Comment: There's a boycott of GoDaddy b/c of SOPA.

Comment: @slaks: when I set, at the top of the form, my domain, Google answer me that: it's not an available domain.

Comment: @Zagzag: You're using the wrong form.

Comment: @Slaks: strange, 'cause I'm on this page http://www.google.com/a/cpanel/premier/new?hl=en ; Google answer me "Google Apps does not currently support this domain name.".

Comment: @Zagzag: What domain name?

Answer (score 0):

As an update to this question, Google now has a domain registration service for anyone who wants to know. It's at https://domains.google/ . Google Domains recently launched on January of 2015.